# Spring boot API - How to ensure no concurrency issues

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I'm still in the process of learning Java / spring and I think I'm getting better. Now at this point I'm able to build a rest api BUT I'm at a lost at how to ensure I've no concurrency issues . I've read many topics regarding making the API stateless or making my POJO's immutable but I'm sure if in my case below I need to. And if I did, I'm actually unsure how my code can function by making everything final in my POJO.

If someone could help me learn here I'd be VERY grateful. Thank you for your time

Below i have a POJO called User:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "UserProfiles")
public class User {
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    private String _id;

    @JsonView({ProfileViews.Intro.class, ProfileViews.Full.class})
    private String userId;

    @JsonView({ProfileViews.Intro.class, ProfileViews.Full.class})
    private String name;

    @JsonView({ProfileViews.Intro.class, ProfileViews.Full.class})
    private String displayName;

    @DBRef
    @JsonView({ProfileViews.Full.class})
    private UserInterests personalInterests;

    @DBRef
    @JsonIgnore
    private ProfileFollows profileFollowDetails;

}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "ProfileFollows")
public class ProfileFollows {
    @Id
    //Id of The Mongo Document
    private String id;

    //The Id of the User Profile who owns the document
    private String userId;

    //A list containing the Ids of the Users who have followed the Profile belonging to userId
    private List<String> profileFollowedByUserIds;

    //A list containing the Ids of the Profiles the current user has followed
    private List<String> profileFollowingByUserList;
}
```

And here is my Service layer where I create and update the user

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDal userDal;

    public User createNewUserAccount(String userId, String userName) {
        //check If userId already in DB

        if (checkIfUserIdExits(userId)) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException("Cannot create User with Id { " + userId + " }, a user with this Id already " +
                    "exists");
        }

        //Create a Empty / Base New User Object
        User newUser = new User();
    
        UserInterests userInterests = new UserInterests();
        userInterests.setUserId(userId);
        userInterests.setPersonalInterestsExtras(null);
        userInterests.setCreatedDate(Instant.now());
        userInterests.setLastUpdatedAt(Instant.now());
        userInterestsDAL.save(userInterests);

        newUser.setPersonalInterests(userInterests);

        ProfileFollows userProfileFollows = new ProfileFollows();
        userProfileFollows.setUserId(userId);
        userProfileFollows.setProfileFollowedByUserIds(new ArrayList<>());
        userProfileFollows.setProfileFollowingByUserList(new ArrayList<>());
        newUser.setProfileFollowDetails(profileFollowsDAL.save(userProfileFollows));


        newUser.setUserId(userId);
        newUser.setDisplayName(generateUserDisplayName(userName));
        newUser.setCreatedDate(Instant.now());
        newUser.setLastUpdatedAt(Instant.now());

        //save the new User Profile to the DB
        return userDal.save(newUser);
    }
```

Here is my UserDAL:

```
public interface UserDal {
    /**
     * Method to check if a user exists with a given user Id
     * @param Id -- Id of user to look up where id is a string
     * @return
     */
    Boolean existsById(String Id);

    /**
     * Method to save a user to the DB
     * @param user -- User object to save to the DB
     * @return
     */
    User save(User user);
}
```

My User Repository / DALImpl:

```
@Repository
public class UserDALImpl implements UserDal {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public UserDALImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

  @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        return mongoTemplate.save(user);
    }
```

And lastly my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class CreateProfileController {

    @Autowired
    public CreateProfileController() {
    }

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Allows for the creation of a user Profile")
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public User createUserProfile(@RequestParam(name = "userId") String userId,
                                  @RequestParam(name = "displayName", required = true, defaultValue = "AnonymousDev") String displayName) {

        if (userId.equals("")) throw new BadRequestException("UserId cannot be blank");

        if (userService.checkIfUserIdExits(userId)) {
            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException("Unable to create user with Id { " + userId + " }, the " +
                    "userId already exists");
        }
        return userService.createNewUserAccount(userId, displayName);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are not using any parallel operations or if any API/library you use do not operate parallely on your object then concurrency issues won't be a problem. In other cases you could follow some synchronisation techniques. Note that final fields are thread safe (not always) because you cannot set values to those fields. If you are setting values as required, then it is not final.

Comment: Even if your object is declared final, you could concurrently update its value. Final just prevents the changing of an object reference. Hence making a field final is not the only way to handle concurrency issues. Updates to commonly accessed objects should be synchronised. You could do some search on synchronisation techniques.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @GauthamM, when you say "If you are not using any parallel operations " Do you mean like multithreads changing the same object? If I understand correctly this will not be the case (right?? :-)) Since the create new profile method instantiates its own new User Object to modify

Comment: i was saying it in a general. Not specific to the code in question